# mysql to ignore all rows if column has a particular data

Tags: mysql, sql

I can select set of data by using joins but how I would like to select 0 rows if a column value has one particular data.
In my example I would like to select 0 rows if the patient_id =63 and status='SCHEDULED'.

`select surgical_appointment_id, patient_id, status from surgical_appointment;`

[image]

Comment: Do you still want other patient_id's?`

Comment: Poor sample data, it lacks different patiend_id's, having dfferent status combinations.

Comment: Yes I do, its just an example of one patient id, but the condition is if the status is scheduled no data should visible for that particular patient

Comment: What would be the problem in using a `WHERE` clause? What have you tried to solve this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `not exists` :

```
select sa.*
from surgical_appointment sa
where not exists (select 1 
                  from surgical_appointment saa 
                  where saa.patient_id =  sa.patient_id and
                        saa.status = 'SCHEDULED'
                 );
```

By this way you will not get scheduled `patient`s. If you want specific patient add filter with `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh, my approach was also towards NOT EXISTS but somehow I couldn't formulated the query, cheers.. it works now

Comment: is that any other way to ignore the passed data? because in my case is id which is not predefined